# Full referencing from exercises

Tags: hyperref, ref

I have the following setup:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup
{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=teal,
}
\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[exercise]{label*=\thechapter.\arabic*.,ref=\thechapter.\arabic*, 
    before={\section*{\hfil{Exercises -- \thechapter}\hfil}}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Exercises -- \thechapter}%
}
\begin{document}
    \let\oldref=\ref 
    \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{#1} in page \pageref{#1}}
    \chapter{title}
    \section{title}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item   bla
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item   \label{key1}
                            bla
                \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{exercise}
        \item 
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item   bla
                        \begin{enumerate}
                            \item   \label{key}
                                    bla                         
                            \item   bla
                        \end{enumerate}
                \item   bla
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{exercise}
    Exercise \ref{key}, \ref{key1}.
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output.
[image]
What I want `\ref` to produce for `exercise` is "1.1. 1.(a) in page 1" and for the first `enumerate` staff "1.(a) in page 1". Of course both of them should be hyperlinks as they are now. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I think that the format you desire is rather confusing to the reader, it can easily be achieved using `\setlist*` in the `before` key. You should, however, *not* redefine `\ref` in that way! It will certainly break things. Rather, define a new command, say `\myref`, to output the page number as well.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linktoc=all,
  linkcolor=black,
  citecolor=teal,
}

\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[exercise]{
  label*=\thechapter.\arabic*.,
  ref=\thechapter.\arabic*, 
  before={%
    \section*{\hfil{Exercises -- \thechapter}}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Exercises -- \thechapter}%
    \setlist*[enumerate,1]{ref=\theexercisei.~\arabic*}%
    \setlist*[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi.(\alph*)}%
  },
}
\setlist*[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi.(\alph*)}

\newcommand*\myref[1]{\ref{#1} on page~\pageref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}
\section{title}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item   bla
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{key1}
          bla
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{exercise}
  \item 
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item bla
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \label{key}
              bla                         
            \item bla
        \end{enumerate}
      \item bla
    \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
Exercise~\myref{key}, \myref{key1}.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion. I have one query though. How do I modify the code if the question in `exercise` starts like `\item \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)] \item \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*), font=\itshape]` ? If the query is not clear here, I can edit the question as well. Please help.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul I'm not sure I understand. If you locally change the `label` key, just change the `ref` key as well. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes. I want to change the `label` locally. Also tried with the `ref` key in the `setlist*` options, but could not get the result. Can you please modify the options with the given example as in my previous comment? Thanks.

Comment: The way I modified is the following `\setlist*[enumerate,1]{ref=\theexercisei.~(\alph*)}
  \setlist*[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi.(\roman*)}
 },
}
\setlist*[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi.(\roman*)}`

Comment: @SubhajitPaul You don't have to use `\setlist`. If you change `label` in the optional argument of the list environment, change `ref` there, too. `\begin{enumerate}[label={...}, ref={...}]`